# Program stuck to update complete list of accounts in Dynamics CRM using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, account

I've following code snippet that is grabbing all active accounts from CRM and then updating one of the hidden field for each account.  There are around 45,000 active accounts resides in CRM and that is why I am using paging and grabbing 5000 records from each page. It start updating records from page 1 and grab first 5000 records but hang on 3100th account and don't move further. I am here for seeking your kind advise/suggestions to do the needful. TIA!!!

```
string temp1 = string.Empty;
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "account",
  ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "new_latestpolicydate","new_latestpolicydate_hidden"),
    Criteria = new FilterExpression
    {
        Conditions = { 
            new ConditionExpression("statecode",ConditionOperator.Equal,0)
        }
    }
};

qe.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();
qe.PageInfo.Count = 5000;
qe.PageInfo.PageNumber = 1;
qe.PageInfo.PagingCookie = null;

while (true)
{
    EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);

Console.WriteLine("Page no:\t{0}\nTotal Active Accounts:\t{1}",qe.PageInfo.PageNumber, ec.Entities.Count);
        foreach (Entity item in ec.Entities)
        {
            if (item.Attributes.Contains("new_latestpolicydate"))
            {

                DateTime date;
                date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Attributes["new_latestpolicydate"]);
                temp1 = date.Date.ToString("d");
                item.Attributes["new_latestpolicydate_hidden"] = temp1;
            }
            if (temp1 != string.Empty)
            {
                service.Update(item);
                Console.Write("\r{0} are accounts updated", i++);
            }
        }
        if (ec.MoreRecords)
        {
            qe.PageInfo.PageNumber++;
            qe.PageInfo.PagingCookie = ec.PagingCookie;
        }
        else
        { break; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. I have 2 suggestions:

1. Try to rewrite code without trying to update record immediately. Try to retrieve all records and only after update all data.
2. For such tasks I can suggest to use SSIS - it's much more easier. [KingswaySoft adapter](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm) is free for such kind of operations.

Comment: I'd debugged my code and found that when it went for taking records for second page the connection expired and it send this exception `The HTTP request to 'https://XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc' was aborted`

Comment: Unfortunately I have never experienced mentioned kind of exceptions so I don't know other way helping you except mentioned.

Comment: The issue is resolved. Actually there is a plugin that executed as soon as account is updated. So, disabling plugin get the work done.

Comment: @MohsinTester You can do such tasks by simple SQL queries which is too fast , no need to write such long query expression in future if you face such things to do, as it takes too long to update.

Comment: Wait, you aren't suggesting that we should do updates in SQL are you? 
As for the original question, you might have had an issue with the connection to the CRM timing out and you need to refresh the token IIRC.